# Count length and number of words in string

Tags: c, string

I am a beginner in C. I am trying to print out the length and the number of words in a string inputted by user. I have trouble dealing with the counting of words. I attempt to scan the number of the space character , then add 1 to the result. It is guaranteed that each word is only separated by one space.

I executed the code, and inputted

```
I go to school by bus.
```

The second output was not as I expected

```
22
24
```

`22` is correct since it is indeed the length of the string, but I do not understand why it prints `24` instead of `6` (result of 5 spaces plus 1).

The code is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char in[256];
    int cl=0,cw,i;
    scanf("%[^\n]",&in);
    cw=strlen(in);
    for(i=0;i<=cw;i++){
        if(in[i]=' '){
            cl=cl+1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",cw);
    printf("%d\n",cl+1);
    return 0;
}
```

What went wrong, and how can I get a correct output?

Comment: @xing and why's that _required_ here? It's a good practice, but not an error reason here. :)

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @xing `cl` is already initialized to 0, `cw` is initialized by `strlen` and `i` is initialized by `for (i = 0;...)`.

Comment: I pasted an outdated code that was in my clipboard, where `cl` wasn't initialized yet. My fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(in[i]=' '){
```

will always be true, you need to change it to

```
if(in[i]==' '){
```

Answer (score 4):

2 mistakes I see in your code.

1. `if(in[i]=' ')` should be `if(in[i]==' ')`

> `==` Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not. If yes, then the condition becomes true.
>
> `=` Simple assignment operator. Assigns values from right side operands to left side operand.

2. `i<=cw` should be `i<cw`

> indexing starts with 0 in C.

Answer (score 2):

As Pras said, on ifs you normally use ==, because you are comparing and it returns true or false
If you just use = it attributes (insert) a value on the right to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You should use == instead of = in the if statement that detects the space.

The assignment operator, = gives is always true if the number is asssigned to a nonzero value.

The equivalence operator, == is what actually compares whether two numbers have the same value.

It may be surprising that the assignment operator can actually test whether or not a number is zero(at least on x860. This is because jz, one of the testing instructions, checks something called a flag register (a special memory location) that contains information about the arithmetic operation most recently executed. == does a cmp, which subtracts both numbers from each other to see if it is 0. Jz stands for "jump if zero", so two equal numbers result to the "jump" to the instructions in the if statement. When = is used, the compiler uses jz instead (in order to comply with the c idea that nonzero number in if is true), which results in the behavior described above.